# Clone method not visible

Tags: java, clone

why do i am getting clone method not visible of object class

```
class a7 implements Cloneable
{
    int id;
    float f;

}

class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        a7 x=new a7();
        //      x.clone(); //here i am getting the error
    }   

}
```

though clone method is protected and it is accessible by subclasses and and the one in the same package and we know that every class by default are subclasses of object class

Comment: Are `a7` and `test` classes in the same package?

Comment: `clone()` is `protected`. Standard practice is to override it, make it `public` and make it return your type rather than `Object`. Don't forget to call `super.clone()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider any reason or that?

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions. Classes should be in `PascalCase`. `camelCase` is reserved for variables.

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/::refer this link

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes they are

Comment: By implementing `cloneable`, the `clone` method should be public. But since you don't redefine it, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html):

> By convention, classes that implement this interface should override
>   Object.clone (which is protected) with a public method. See
>   Object.clone() for details on overriding this method.

I would also check out [Joshua Bloch's advice on Cloneable](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

> If you've read the item about cloning in my book, especially if you
>   read between the lines, you will know that I think clone is deeply
>   broken. There are a few design flaws, the biggest of which is that the
>   Cloneable interface does not have a clone method. And that means it
>   simply doesn't work: making something Cloneable doesn't say anything
>   about what you can do with it. Instead, it says something about what
>   it can do internally. It says that if by calling super.clone
>   repeatedly it ends up calling Object's clone method, this method will
>   return a field copy of the original

.